# How to add 'Enable Customer User' Button in account object record

Tags: community

[image]

How to add 'Enable Customer User' Button in account object record

Answer (score 1):

As outlined in [Enable the Customer Portal for Contacts and Person Accounts](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=contacts_customer_portal.htm&type=0), Person Accounts and Contacts may be enabled as Customer Users. Make sure that the Account you are looking at is a Person Account, and not a Business Account. More generally speaking, users are *people*, not *organizations*.

Comment: 'Enable Customer User' button is not viewing on person account, How it will come, Could you please help me in this

Comment: @Rehan Did you check the Page Layout in Setup > Customize > Accounts > Person Accounts > Page Layouts?

Comment: The account you are showing looks like a normal Account which you cannot enable as a community user. If you have person accounts you would be able to do it there or on the individual contacts records.

Answer (score 0):

At least you need to add the button to Page Layout for Lightning experience